# C++: Template class binary operator overloading - seg fault?

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

The following describe the example I have which works:

`header`:

```
const size_t N = 10;
//    template<size_t N>
class SymbolicMonomial {
public:
    int powers[N];
    int constant;

    SymbolicMonomial() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            this->powers[i] = 0;
        }
        this->constant = 1;
    }

    SymbolicMonomial(int variable): SymbolicMonomial(){
        this->powers[variable] = 1;
    }

    static SymbolicMonomial as_monomial(int value){
        auto result = SymbolicMonomial();
        result.constant = value;
        return result;
    }

    bool is_constant(){
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            if(this->powers[i] > 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

//    template<size_t N>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const SymbolicMonomial value){
    out << value.constant << "(";
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        out << value.powers[i] << ", ";
    }
    out << value.powers[N-1] << ")";
}

//    template<size_t N>
SymbolicMonomial operator*(SymbolicMonomial lhs, SymbolicMonomial rhs) {
    SymbolicMonomial result = SymbolicMonomial();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        result.powers[i] = lhs.powers[i] + rhs.powers[i];
    }
    result.constant = lhs.constant * rhs.constant;
    return result;
}
```

The `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
auto t_a = symbolic::SymbolicMonomial(2);
auto t_b = symbolic::SymbolicMonomial(1);
auto t_c = t_b*t_a*t_a;
std::cout << t_c << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

And everything is fine. However, I wanted to change the whole thing to have a template argument `<N>` instead of a constant. Thus this is the templated code:
`header.h`:

```
template<const size_t N>
class SymbolicMonomial {
public:
    int powers[N];
    int constant;

    SymbolicMonomial() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            this->powers[i] = 0;
        }
        this->constant = 1;
    }

    SymbolicMonomial(int variable): SymbolicMonomial(){
        this->powers[variable] = 1;
    }

    static SymbolicMonomial as_monomial(int value){
        auto result = SymbolicMonomial<N>();
        result.constant = value;
        return result;
    }

    bool is_constant(){
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            if(this->powers[i] > 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

template<const size_t N>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const SymbolicMonomial<N> value){
    out << value.constant << "(";
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        out << value.powers[i] << ", ";
    }
    out << value.powers[N-1] << ")";
}

template<const size_t N>
SymbolicMonomial<N> operator*(SymbolicMonomial<N> lhs, SymbolicMonomial<N> rhs) {
    SymbolicMonomial<N> result = SymbolicMonomial<N>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        result.powers[i] = lhs.powers[i] + rhs.powers[i];
    }
    result.constant = lhs.constant * rhs.constant;
    return result;
}
```

And `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
auto t_a = symbolic::SymbolicMonomial<10>(2);
auto t_b = symbolic::SymbolicMonomial<10>(1);
auto t_c = t_b*t_a*t_a;
std::cout << t_c << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Now the non template version works as expected, however the templated one fails with code 139 (SEGFAULT). Firstly, I do not understand why the code fails if someone can explain and secondly how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const SymbolicMonomial<N> value)` isn't returning a value. For me, in Visual Studio, that resulted in a compile error. Adding `return out;` to the end of the function lead to the code working without an ACCESS_VIOLATION (Windows flavor of a SEGFAULT).

All of your bound-checking looks correct, so, if I had to guess, I'd say that your compiler is ignoring the missing return, and you're entering a spooky space known as *undefined behavior* when you work with a return value that was never actually set.

Assuming you're using GCC, you can set `-Werror=return-type` to throw compile errors when you make these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Good catch. The default g++ flags does indeed not issue a warning. I.e. the non-template version working was an (un)lucky fluke.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I deleted the return statement when copying some code around and did not really pay attention to that (I thought it's something from the operator overloading of the multiplication). Probably should use the flag!